# Use of InkManager in a Windows 8.1 Store Application crashes into System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Exception

Tags: windows, store, comexception, inkmanager

I us the InkManager to capture strokes on a canvas. On most machines the application works (Windows 8.1 and Windows 10).
But on some Windows 10 Machines the Construtctor of the InkManager throws an exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException, "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Framework Target: Windows 8.1 Store app

Running OS: Windows 10

Version: 1511

Build: 10586.753

Altough there are machines running same os version and build on which theInkManager seems to work fine.

On the Machines where its not working it is persistent. Reinstalling the Application wont solve the problem.
The error can be produced by installing the app from the store or via remote debugger.
I cannot say more about it. It did not figure out what causes the exception.
I tried to figure it out for two days, so if anyone can give me a hint, it would be highly appreciated!

edit:
The error can be reproduced using the InkManager Demo Application from the Microsoft example library:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples

Comment: Set breakpoints on RoOriginateError and RoOriginateErrorW. Hopefully they will give you more information (there is a string message parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, the solution is to have both English (US) Handwriting and Optical Character Recognition via Languages setting panel.

> [image: screenshot]

I think that I need to have English since it is my Windows's display language.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks man. That was acctually the solution to the problem. At the end we went with the Microsoft Tech Support, which came up with this solution within an hour.